# Starting same thread from a foreach loop not working

Tags: vb.net, foreach

Is there a way to start same Thread form `foreach` loop

```
Sub
For Each lvItem As ListViewItem In _ListView.SelectedItems
    tThread = New Thread(AddressOf Me.myFunction())
    tThread .Start()
Next
End Sub


Sub myFunction()
//Code
End Sub
```

In my case, when i select one item from list it is working fine...but when i select more than one files it odes not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to select multiple files (which are file paths) from ListView and convert them in mp3 files but with above solution. it converts first selected file successfully but then stops.

Creating a separate thread for each file is sub-optimal.  In some cases, this can actually result in *worse* performance than doing them all sequentially, because your system will spend too much time switching back and forth between different threads.  Instead, you want to choose a small number of threads and queue your items for time by those threads.

There are a lot of ways to implement this:

- You can write custom code that bases the number of threads on the number of physical processor cores (greater of 2 or the number of cores - 1 is common). This is a lot of extra work, and is error prone.
- You can use the built-in in [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx).  This is great, but it can be tricky to track progress of your items.
- You can use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).  This requires .Net 4, but it's probably your best option by far.  The extra work upfront learning the concepts will also be a huge payoff, and it sounds like Microsoft is basing some of the more important features in .Net 5 around the Task concept.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that instead of having one variable `tThread` storing the thread, you probably meant to store all the threads, so instead have a `List` of them. So something like:

```
Sub
    Dim threads as New List(Of Thread)
    For Each lvItem As ListViewItem In _ListView.SelectedItems
        tThread = New Thread(AddressOf Me.myFunction())
        tThread .Start()
        threads.Add(tThread)
    Next
End Sub
```

Otherwise, if there's another issue, please supply more details.

Comment: I want to select multiple files (which are file paths) from ListView and convert them in mp3 files but with above solution. it converts first selected file successfully but then stops.

Comment: @m.qayyum: In your code you're not actually sending in any filepaths to `myFunction` though, so how does it knows which paths? Is it possible that the code in `myFunction` gets hold of the paths by itself and there's something wrong that makes it get the same path for every thread?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the items are selected?  I tried the following with a few items in the listview and it worked as expected.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    For Each lvItem As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
        Dim t As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf myFunction)
        t.Start(lvItem)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub myFunction(ByVal lvi As Object)
    Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = CType(lvi, ListViewItem)
    Debug.WriteLine(lvItem.Text)
End Sub
```